# Rails: Controller method parameter being interpreted as a file format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

When I make a call to `redirect_to` it is intepreting the parameter I am trying to pass to the controller method, as the file format of the route. Which results in the following route:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/application/pay.1798
```

where `1798` is the id of the object I am trying to pass to the Controller Method referenced by the `redirect_to`.

Here is the `redirect_to`

```
redirect_to pay_path(@school_application.id)
```

and here is the other controller method that is supposed to use the id passed in to the `redirect_to`

```
   def pay
     @school_application = SchoolApplication.find(params[:id])
   end
```

However this does not actually set the `params` hash when `pay_path` is called, but just interprets the variable as the file format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was passing the parameter in wrong, as I did not assign the id to a key in the hash.

```
redirect_to pay_path(:id => @school_application.id)
```

this solved it.